# Umbraco 7.4.1 and courier

Tags: umbraco7

After upgrading to 7.4.1 I am unable to Courier Media items.

The first error was that there was no column for help text, So I added this to both environments

```
ALTER TABLE cmsPropertyType ADD helpText NVARCHAR(1000) NULL
```

and now another exception is being thrown when packaging items.

Please can anyone help

```
2016-02-23 12:46:34,722 [39] ERROR Umbraco.Courier.Core.TaskManager -  
[Thread 51] An error occurred consuming task      Umbraco.Courier.Core.Exceptions.PackageException: Unable to load item with id 'Image' from provider 'Media types' ---> 

Umbraco.Courier.Core.Exceptions.RetrieveException: Error retrieving item     [Image] from provider [d8e6ad88-e73a-11df-9492-0800200c9a66]. ---> 

NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException: could not execute query [ SELECT this.id as id10, this.contenttypeNodeId as contentt210, this.sortorder as sortorder10, this.text as text10, this.parentGroupId as parentGr510_ FROM cmsPropertyTypeGroup this_ WHERE this.contenttypeNodeId = @p0 ] Positional parameters: #0>1032 [SQL: SELECT this.id as id10, this.contenttypeNodeId as contentt210, this.sortorder as sortorder10, this.text as text10, this.parentGroupId as parentGr510 FROM cmsPropertyTypeGroup this_ WHERE this_.contenttypeNodeId = @p0] ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'parentGroupId'.
```

Comment: You should report this at issues.umbraco.org, it doesn't sound right.

Comment: I am going to try a controlled test to make sure that there is a comparability issue with the versions. Then if it happens again I will put a ticket in